# python datapanda: getting values from rows into list

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to get the values of my dataframe's rows into a list:

```
    A  B  C
1   2  3  2
2   4  2  6

list1 = [2, 3 2]
list2 = [4, 2, 6]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `values.tolist()`:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame({'a': [2,4], 'b': [3,2], 'c': [2,6]})
print df

list1 = df.irow(0).values.tolist()
list2 = df.irow(1).values.tolist()
```

**output:**

```
   a  b  c
0  2  3  2
1  4  2  6

[2L, 3L, 2L]
[4L, 2L, 6L]
```

If you want it as `int` you can map the list using `map(int, list1)`